# How to write a Lottery with varying odds in R

Tags: r

I'm attempting to write an R code to generate "n" iterations of playing the game described in the image below (Ellsberg Paradox).

```
Ellsberg <- function(n){
  r <- 30
  b <- floor(runif(n,0,61))
  y <- 60 - b
}
```

I essentially want to turn this block of code into a function which will output which colour was randomly selected from the three options; Red, Yellow or Black given the random number of black and yellow balls

[Ellsberg Paradox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb1l8.png)

I've used the above function to output a n matrices which have 3 rows of differing length but no idea how to move from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate pulling from the Three Color Ellsberg Urn scenario as follows:

```
Ellsberg <- function(){
  b=sample(0:60,1)
  sample(c(rep("r", 30),rep("b",b),rep("y",60-b)),1)
}
```

You can then replicate this, `n` times.

```
set.seed(1234)
n=1000
table(replicate(1000, Ellsberg()))
```

Output:

```
  b   r   y 
347 321 332
```